# Expecting a Vector returned from for loop

Tags: scala, for-loop, yield

Scala noob here.

Here is my simple for loop

```
  def forExampleStoreValues = {
    println(">>forExampleStoreValues");
    val retVal = for{i <- 1 to 5 if i % 2 == 0}  yield i;
    println("retVal=" + retVal);    
  }
```

My expectation is when I call this, the last val will be returned automatically. However when I call this from main,

```
object MainRunner {
  def main(args: Array[String]){
    println("Scala stuff!");  // println comes from Predef which definitions for anything inside a Scala compilation unit. 
    runForExamples();
  }

  def runForExamples() {
    val forLE = new ForLoopExample(); // No need to declare type.
    println("forExampleStoreValues=" +forLE.forExampleStoreValues)  
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
>>forExampleStoreValues
retVal=Vector(2, 4)
forExampleStoreValues=()
```

So then I try to explictly return the retval.

```
  def forExampleStoreValues = {
    println(">>forExampleStoreValues");
    val retVal = for{i <- 1 to 5 if i % 2 == 0}  yield i;
    println("retVal=" + retVal);    
    return retval;
  }
```

This gives:

```
method forExampleStoreValues has return statement; needs result type
```

So I change function signature to:

```
 def forExampleStoreValues():Vector
```

which gives:

```
Vector takes type parameters
```

At this stage, not sure what to put in and I want to ensure I am not doing something I don't need to do.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need an explicit return. The last expression in your method will always be returned.

```
def forExampleStoreValues = {
  println(">>forExampleStoreValues")
  val retVal = for{i <- 1 to 5 if i % 2 == 0}  yield i
  println("retVal=" + retVal)  
  retVal
}
```

This also means that if you end your method with `println(...)`, it will return `()` of type `Unit`, since that is the return type of `println`. If you do you an explicit return (usually because you want to return early), you need to specify the result type. The result type is `Vector[Int]`, not `Vector`.

Comment: that just returns forExampleStoreValues=(), as if the Vector is not returned.  It should print it.

Comment: how do you invoke the function and how do you output what is returned?

Comment: scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def forExampleStoreValues = {
  println(">>forExampleStoreValues")
  val retVal = for{i <- 1 to 5 if i % 2 == 0}  yield i
  println("retVal=" + retVal)  
  retVal
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

forExampleStoreValues: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]

scala> forExampleStoreValues
>>forExampleStoreValues
retVal=Vector(2, 4)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(2, 4)

Comment: I get that from the interpretator as well. However, I do not get anything when I invoke it from a Scala object as I described in original question. Any ideas why?

Comment: No, you should add the complete code of that object to your question.

Comment: maybe you are calling an old version of ForLoopExample. What's your build process?

Comment: everything in the same eclipse project using type safe plugin.

Comment: I have cleaned project. Same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The last value in a Scala function is returned. The explicit return is not necessary.

Your code can be simplified to this where the `for` expression returns a `IndexSeq[Int]` which is inferred by the compiler.

```
def forExampleStoreValues = {
  for{i <- 1 to 5 if i % 2 == 0}  yield i;    
}

scala>forExampleStoreValues
res0: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(2, 4)
```

The expression `for{i <- 1 to 5 if i % 2 == 0}  yield i;` returns an instance of `Vector[Int]` which implements the trait `IndexedSeq`. So, to manually specify the type you can add `IndexedSeq[Int]` to the `for` expression.

```
 def forExampleStoreValues: IndexedSeq[Int] = {
   for{i <- 1 to 5 if i % 2 == 0}  yield i;    
 }
```